# Android application development by using OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, development, nominatim

I have managed to install my own tile server for one country and we can see the map, it's working.

The END Goal is, we will build a vehicle tracking software by using our tiles.
Currently we are on learning stage as we never worked with OSM or its API. Since we are going to host everything in-house, I just wanted to get a basic concept,

From an administrator point of view, what tools I need to configure to allow our developer to work with OpenStreetMap for vehicle tracking?

I refer to this site https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop, so do just Need to install Rubyport? That will allow developer to start working? I already have Tiles working.

Comment: have a look at https://www.traccar.org/

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking to make a complete system with API's, Devices and Servers. The whole answer would have to incorporate many parts.

An alternative is an existing application [traccar](https://www.traccar.org/) which is open source and should be in the line of what you are doing.

Comment: Hello,  yes, this is right , the i have install the Server ( tiles) , but what i need to understand, how mobile developer will use those tiles to create map to show where is my vechile ? what kind of extra application do i need install for them to get this facilities,

Comment: I mean, what Do i need to use or install   for creating API so that developer can use those API to show real time vechile in open street map ?

We are in learning stage now ..we are not going to use any 3rd party solution.